# using jquery load to make a variable

Tags: jquery, variables, load

I have a jQuery `.load()` function that finds a specific DIV in another page, I'd like to store the ID of that DIV into a variable, but I'm not entirely sure how to do it.

```
$('#bow_1_img').load('http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/inventory.html .bow:first');
```

so this would load the contents of the first div with the class bow, `.bow:first`, into `#bow_1_img` but instead I'd like to load it's `ID` into a variable, any idea on how to do that?

```
$.get('http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/inventory.html', function(data) {
    var elem = $(data).find('.bow:first'),
          bow_id = elem.attr('id');
}); 
$("#bow_1").click(function() {
        window.location.href = "http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/inventory.html#" + bow_id;
});
```

Comment: The ID of the `.bow:first` element?  Why do you want to load it into a variable?  `.load` is asynchronous.

Comment: I'm neither entirely sure how to do it, cause you're asking how to store the "`ID of that DIV`" ..... what DIV ? what ID, you're loading a CLASS element. Can you try to be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`load()` is just a shortcut for `$.get`, if you only need the ID, use $.get

```
$.get('http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/inventory.html', function(data) {
    var elem = $(data).find('.bow:first'),
          ID = elem.attr('id');
     $("#bow_1").click(function() {
        window.location.href = "http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/inventory.html#" + bow_id;
     });
});
```

remember that it's async, so ID will only be available after the ajax function completes.

Comment: can I just take out the part with bow_1_img, I don't actually want to add it to that.  I'd like to take the id and make it into a link like so: $("#bow_1").click(function() {
        window.location.href = "http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/inventory.html#" + ID;
});

Comment: Yes you can, you don't have to append it at all !

Comment: can you look to see what I just added to my question and see if that looks right?  It doesn't work when I click #bow_1 for some reason

Comment: That's because it's asynchronous, when you add the bow_id, the data is not retrieved from the server yet !

Comment: hmm, can I fix that?  How do you add the click function into that?

Comment: Like the code above. It **has** to be inside the complete handler, when the data has been retrieved, it's not available any sooner.